# How to use multiple textures in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es-2.0, textures, glkit

I would like to set up a texture array to use for my shape. I have researched this topic on the internet but there are hardly any references a newbie like me can make use of.
Again, what I am trying to achieve, is a texture array that I can use to map different textures onto the different faces of my shape. 
As of now I have got only one texture that I generate from a UIView.

My core questions are:

- How do I set up this array ?
- How do I load textures into that array ?
- How do I use this array ?

**Here is my code:**

```
- (void)setupGL {



    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.myContext];

    self.effect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init];
    self.layer.contentsScale = 2.0;
    BOOL useTexture = YES;

    // Create default framebuffer object.
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &defaultFrameBuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, defaultFrameBuffer);

    myView = [[MyView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,320)];

    self.effect.transform.projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(45.0f,0.9f, 0.01f, .08f);
    self.effect.transform.projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4Translate(self.effect.transform.projectionMatrix, 0, 0.1, 1.2);
    rotMatrix = GLKMatrix4Translate(self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix,0,0,-2);
    self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = rotMatrix;


        /*********************
         MAPPING UIVIEW ONTO THE FACE
         ****************/

        CGColorSpaceRef colourSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

        self.effect.texture2d0.enabled = true;

        GLubyte *pixelBuffer = (GLubyte *)malloc(
                                                 4 *
                                                 myView.bounds.size.width * coordToPixScale *
                                                 myView.bounds.size.height * coordToPixScale);


            CGContextRef context =
            CGBitmapContextCreate(pixelBuffer,
                                  myView.bounds.size.width*coordToPixScale, myView.bounds.size.height*coordToPixScale,
                                  8, 4*myView.bounds.size.width *coordToPixScale,
                                  colourSpace,
                                  kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
            CGColorSpaceRelease(colourSpace);

            // draw the view to the buffer
            [myView.layer renderInContext:context];

            // upload to OpenGL
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,
                         GL_RGBA,
                         myView.bounds.size.width * coordToPixScale, myView.bounds.size.height * coordToPixScale, 0,
                         GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixelBuffer);

            glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

            // clean up
            CGContextRelease(context);




        glGenBuffers(1, &texArray);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texArray);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(TexCoords), TexCoords, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,0);

        /**************************
         ******************************************/
        free(pixelBuffer);




    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthBuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthBuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, myView.bounds.size.width * coordToPixScale, myView.bounds.size.height * coordToPixScale);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthBuffer);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexArray);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexArray);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,0);



}
```

**This method is called when it gets drawn:**

```
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect {

    self.opaque = NO;

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    [self.effect prepareToDraw];

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, sizeof(Vertices) / (sizeof(GLfloat) * 3));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you are using [GLKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKit_Collection/_index.html) I think you can load the textures more easily. First create your `CGImageRef`:

```
   CGImageRef image0 = 
  [[UIImage imageNamed:@"image0.png"] CGImage];
```

Load that into a `GLKTextureInfo` ivar `textureInfo0` as follows:

```
  self.textureInfo0 = [GLKTextureLoader 
  textureWithCGImage:image1
  options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
     [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], 
     GLKTextureLoaderOriginBottomLeft, nil] 
  error:NULL];
```

Do exactly the same with your second texture. That should be named `textureInfo1`.

Loading the texture coords is done with `glEnableVertexAttribArray` and `glVertexAttribPointer` using the `GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0` attribute. I think you have that set up above. You will need to map the coordinates from your texture to the target triangles. For example, if you wanted to draw a square - which composes of two triangles - you would need to map the S and T coordinates of the source image twice, i.e. for each respective triangle. For example triangle 1 with coords:

```
{0.0f, 0.0f}, {1.0f, 0.0f}, {0.0f, 1.0f}.
```

*(if you plot that you will see it is a triangle)*

Then, the second triangle of the square would be as follows:

```
{1.0f, 0.0f}, {0.0f, 1.0f}, {1.0f, 1.0f}.
```

Next, in your drawing method;

```
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
```

first, set up the initial texture:

```
    self.effect.texture2d0.name = self.textureInfo0.name;
    self.effect.texture2d0.target = self.textureInfo0.target;

    [self.effect prepareToDraw];
```

Draw your triangles as need be with `glDrawArrays`. Then, replace with the second texture:

```
    self.effect.texture2d0.name = self.textureInfo1.name;
    self.effect.texture2d0.target = self.textureInfo1.target;

   [self.effect prepareToDraw];
```

and draw the rest of the triangles with `glDrawArrays`. They will use the second texture.

Continue replacing `self.effect.texture2d0.name` and `self.effect.texture2d0.target` with different `GLKTextureInfo` instances to draw the different textures.